# Weird return value of copyOf method in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to copy an array in Java and I used the method copyOf. Here's my code and the weird return value. I was expecting {10,50,40}, but it returns [I@35960f05. What exactly is this? 
Thanks!![image]

Comment: If you already know of the Arrays class, you should know of Arrays.toString

Comment: Isn't the same happening when you do `println(arr1)`? :)

Answer (score 1):

int arr2[] is an array of integers. You have to iterate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with copyOf method, you have to iterate your int array (arr2) while printing.

---

Or you can use [`Arrays.toString(int[] a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) method.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating Array elements, you may print the copy of array. So it will return the `toString()` and it may print accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default output of the Array.toString() method, which is automatically called by Sytem.out.println(obj). This out starts with a '[' indicating, that it is an Array, followed by the type 'I' for integer. There are also other types 'B' for Byte, S for String and so on. Then it is follwed by in internal address of you array.

There is a convenience method in the Arrays Class, which is also called toString, that iterates over the array and prints out the elements.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
```

This can also be done in an explicit for loop.

```
System.out.print("{");
for ( int val : arr2 )
{
   System.out.print("" + val + ",");
}
System.out.print("}");
```